# Out-dated duplicates definition in Help Center

Tags: discussion, questions, help-center, duplicates

We recently had a discussion in The 2nd Monitor about a [post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/222209/toggling-a-class-in-js) being closed as a duplicate of [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/222042). I had flagged it based on a [Rule I found in the Help Center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions):

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If
> those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this
> question to explain how it is different or ask a new question.

However, at Code Review, I was informed about a different policy regarding *marking questions as duplicate*.

- [Rule on CR: check answer by 200_success](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8/how-do-we-define-duplicate-questions)
- [Additional information](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5895/harmless-duplicate-or-are-we-being-taken-advantage-of/5896#5896)

#### Change Request

I would like to request the [Help Center (duplicates)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) to be updated with the definition used in CR for marking duplicates.

Comment: I don't believe it is possible for individual Stack Exchange sites to customize that Help Center page. Only certain pages are meant to be customizable, like the ones related to topicality. The rest are maintained globally for *all* Stack Exchange sites, under the assumption that all sites will adhere to network-wide rules and guidelines. This creates a problem, of course, when individual sites create their own non-standard and unintuitive interpretations of the rules...